# Reactjs - Unable to modify Input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I have created a two components:

1. `Comment` - renders a comment's content and **edit** option(*this option is created from the below component*)
2. `EditComment` - renders a link and onClick of that link renders a
   modal where comment can be edited.

The problem here is the **`input type='textarea'`** is fixed and I am unable to modify it.

Here is the working model of code:

[image: Edit kxw3lvl78v]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this function

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
}
```

`event.target.name` is blank

You have to add a name to the input like so.

```
<Input
    name="content"
    type="textarea"
    placeholder="Edit your Comment here!"
    value={this.state.content}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    required
    />
```